# Using appearance changes the background color table view arrow?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiscrollview

I am developing an app in which i am using themes.For that purpose i am using `Appearance` in iOS.I am able to change the background color of views.So when i change the background color of UIButton then background color of Arrow in `UITable` is also changed.

**Code**

```
 UIColor *color=[UIColor orangeColor];
[[UIButton appearance] setBackgroundColor:color];
```

**Screen**

[image]

Comment: Are you using disclosure indicator or `UIButton` for arrow? If you are using button try using disclosure indicator for this purpose.

Comment: I am using disclosure indicator.@Akhilrajtr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Apple's documentation of the UIAppearance protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/index.html).

> To customize the appearances for instances of a class when contained
>   within an instance of a container class, or instances in a hierarchy,
>   use appearanceWhenContainedIn: to get the appearance proxy for the
>   class.

In your case I would suggest

```
[[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITableView class], nil] setBackgroundColor:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems the arrow is also a object of UIButton...
so you will have to specifically set the backgroundcolor property of arrow in tableview cell.

Comment: I am using disclosure indicator.

Comment: then easy way would be to add your own custom accessoryType , may be a button with image and setting that buttons background color specifically.